# error: Message: element click intercepted:

Tags: python, testing, automation, automated-tests

I have a code, my problem - error, when I starting code. What's wrong ?

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\webdriver firefox\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407')

#Working with radio button

status = driver.find_element_by_id('RESULT_RadioButton-8_0').is_selected()
print(status)

driver.find_element_by_id('RESULT_RadioButton-8_0').click()

status = driver.find_element_by_id('RESULT_RadioButton-8_0').is_selected()
print(status)
```

Comment: Post full code in question in formatted order.

Comment: already solved the problem))

Comment: still post the complete code and post the answer as a separate answer (not in question) or remove question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/XYZ/bin/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407')

status = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name='RESULT_RadioButton-7']").is_selected()
print(status)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[for='RESULT_RadioButton-7_0']").click()

status = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name='RESULT_RadioButton-7']").is_selected()
print(status)
```

> Output :

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
Element <input type="radio" name="RESULT_RadioButton-8" class="multiple_choice" id="RESULT_RadioButton-8_0" value="Radio-0"> is not clickable at point (281, 538). Other element would receive the click: <label for="RESULT_RadioButton-8_0">
```

So you need to click the [`label`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp), not the [`radio input`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp). The label can be located using the following [XPath expression](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727):

```
//label[@for='RESULT_RadioButton-8_0']
```

So you need to change this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('RESULT_RadioButton-8_0').click()
```

to this one:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for=\'RESULT_RadioButton-8_0\']').click()
```